# What is the best approach to clone a website and the clone site will a cold standby

Tags: clone, offsite-backup

Given:
Current website: https://www.classic-site.com/
CMS: Wordpress

My ideas are as follows, but I would like to get inputs and comments from public experts.

1. Password protect the whole site using .htaccess, so search engine would not index the clone site.
2. make a subdomain https://000.classic-site.com/ (from https://www.classic-site.com/)
3. Then when if the problem hits the fan. I can just amend the A record and point it to the new IP.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thank you. Dika

Comment: How to plan for disaster recovery is a complex question not easily answered  in our  simple Q&A format. But in general ensuring that your target audience won't be able to use and confuse your back-up for your live site is a good thing. (Don't forget to document in your DR plan  that such an access restriction needs to be removed when activating the backup)

Comment: Thank for your input @HermanB